# writing to table storage fails without any exception

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

Around 50% of the time these **await AddAsync** are failing to write anything to table  storage and do not produce any exception:

```
public static class OnMichaelvilleBaptistMatchDocumentsTimerTriggered
{
    [FunctionName("OnMichaelvilleBaptistMatchDocumentsTimerTriggered")]
    [StorageAccount("StorageConnectionString")]
    [Singleton]
    public static async Task Run([TimerTrigger("%FileMatcherSchedule%")] TimerInfo y,
        [Table("%Table:UnSharedTable%")] CloudTable filesReceived,
        [Table("%Table:SharedLedgerTable%")] CloudTable matchedSharesReader,
        [Table("%Table:SharedTable%")] IAsyncCollector<Match> matchedShares,
        [Table("%Table:SharedLedgerTable%")] IAsyncCollector<Match> matchedSharesLedger,
        ILogger log)
    {

        //read from filesReceived and matchedSharesReader
        var match = new Match {//some initialization code
                                };

            await matchedShares.AddAsync(match);  // this fails 50% of the time to write data to table storage and does not throw any exception
            await matchedSharesLedger.AddAsync(match);  // this fails 50% of the time to write data to table storage and does not throw any exception
            


        }
    }

public class Match : TableEntity
{
    public Match()
    {
    }

    public string visitId { get; set; }
    public DateTime rtfReceivedAt { get; set; }
    public string rtfFilename { get; set; }
    public DateTime tifReceivedAt { get; set; }
    public string tifFilename { get; set; }
    public string rtfRowKey { get; set; }
    public string tifRowKey { get; set; }
}
}
```

Are the table bindings failing? Perhaps I cannot mix `CloudTable` and `IAsyncCollector`?

**What am I doing wrong? Why is there data loss?**

Comment: Maybe it produces an exception but not at the time you expected because there is on another thread. This is also not visible if the exception works when you already stop the debug. Too hard to find it. What's up if you trycatch them explicit? Did you see the Windows Event Listener?

Comment: More to think, what about fiddle the connection through a fake proxy? You can easily know if there is some kind of "connection/package" lost or the response returned by the server and not catched by the code.

Comment: windows event listener? would that be only if im running storage emulator?

Comment: @LeandroBardelli the fake proxy feels way over my head right now, but i will explore it

Comment: I supose (bad for me) that you are debugging in Visual Studio.

Comment: yes indeed, visual studiop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238922/discussion-between-alex-gordon-and-leandro-bardelli).

Comment: I use them a lot (like gatling) to test web api, but I think it can work with any service. Just a comment and idea, sorry if there is a little poor. This kind of errors are the worst. It's possible to see the connections on the other side? Maybe you have more luck to know if the request are reaching at least.

Comment: do you think if i implement the table connection myself instead of depending on bindings, this might help/??